# Finding the necessary count of a sample given $\sigma$

Tags: statistics, confidence-interval

I am working on the following problem.

```
A state wildlife service wants to estimate the mean number of days that 
each licensed hunter actually hunts during a given season, with a bound 
on the error of estimation equal to 2 hunting days. If data collected .    
in earlier surveys have shown σ to be approximately equal to 10, how 
many hunters must be included in the survey?
```

My understanding is that $\mu$ is being approximated, $\sigma=10$ and the margin of error $m =2$.  I do not think the confidence level is explicit in this problem and yet the solution of this problem states that the sample must be $n=100$.

My understanding is that 
$${z_{\frac{\alpha}{2}}{\sigma \over \sqrt n}}=m$$

So without knowing the critical value or the confidence level we cannot solve for $n$.

The solution for some reason chose the critical value to be $2$.  Is this a conventional thing in statistics or am I missing something?